# Move $title variable to region--content.tpl.php

Tags: theming

I'm having a bit of trouble sorting something out. I'm trying to move the $title variable to region--content.tpl.php.

I think a preprocess function - some variation of `template_preprocess_region` is what I need and then set the variables, but I haven't been able to sort it out or find examples.

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm kind of guessing here, but try $variables['title'], or global $title; before trying to use $title

Comment: Thanks, Geoff. I gave that a try, but no luck. Those are global variables and what I think I need is to make the page variables available to my region template.

Comment: You can go through **Omega** theme code.